# Out Of Memory Android while loading my pub vars

Tags: android, arrays, multidimensional-array

Block Array or multidimensional array Variables. For some reason my app is throwing out of memory on my loading of my pub vars class. This started happening when I started using Block Arrays. It works on actual devices but not on the emulators. Any thoughts? Should I set my block arrays to actual needs?

Current Block Arrays:

```
public static String[][] Name = new String[1000][1000];
```

however I only use maybe 10 or so. Is the device allocating space for the potential of the 1000 and is that why it is errors out? If so, how can I use these as the need may grow and I do not want to put a small limit on it. Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
public static String[][] Name = new String[1000][1000];
```

you are allocating 1 million strings (1000x1000) which is quite a bunch. [If the information on this page is correct each string at least takes 40 bytes](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/string_memory_usage.shtml), so that would be around 39 Mbytes in your case and this can easily be too much memory on the heap for 1 activity. I would start there to refactor if you are only using 10. There is probably a better solution than your approach but without any more details on your code it's hard to give them. But of the top of my head, why not use a `Set<String>` or `List<String>` ?

Edit: So it's seems to me that you just want a Collection that scales dynamically. For that array is not the best choice. There are many of datatypes for that but one simple example whould be an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) which also uses a array as backing datatype but by default will be instanciated with a capacity of 10 and expands dynamically if you continue to add elements

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
stringList.add("string1");
stringList.add("string2");
...
```

If you want each element to have its own list of strings just create an object for that:

```
public class CompoundString {
    private String key;
    private List<String> stringList;
    ...
}
```

and use it like this

```
List<CompoundString> compoundStringList = new ArrayList<CompoundString>();
compoundStringList.add(new CompoundString("string1", new ArrayList<String>());
```

or just use a map:

```
Map<String,List<String>> stringMap = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
stringMap.put("string1", new ArrayList<String>());
```

This is pretty basic concept in most programming languages and I would start to read some docs about the various collections:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html
- http://www.mkyong.com/java/what-is-the-different-between-set-and-list/

Comment: thanks for the comment, I am new to android so not sure what you mean. However you are correct, I switched it to 10 and it loads fine so it must allocate them in memory even if I am not using all of them. Can you explain what you mean by Set<String> and how this can help me. I would like to leave it open ended as I am not sure how many will be input by the user and I do not want to restrict them. I can not however do that like: public static String[][] Name = new String[][];

Comment: Ok I see, just check out the edit, I think you get an idea what you need to do

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have seen this but was not sure this is what you meant. This will go a long way thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. Just added this to the answer: your String[1000][1000] propably allocated around 38MB of Data which is huge for mobile development :)